# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

> 

```
import numpy as np
from getdist import MCSamples
import os
import imageio
import getdist.plots as gplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from scipy.misc import derivative, pade
#from imageio import derivative, pade
from scipy.misc import derivative
#from imageio import pade
from matplotlib import rc
plt.rcParams['text.usetex']=True
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})
dire=os.getcwd() # This will automatically set your current working directory
print(dire)
from scalar_all_eqn import *


#Ophi_i,  rd, li, mi, Orad_i, h=0.7, Ob0=0.045, ns=0.96, sigma_8=0.8
#Ophi,  rd, li, mi,  Orad_i, h, sigma8
#Ophi,     rd, li, mi,  Orad_i, h, 0.045, 0.96, sigma8


samps=np.loadtxt("bao+masers+cmb+hz_c.dat")

names = ['Ophi','rd','li','mi','Orad_i','h','sigma8']
#names = ['Om0','rd','w0','wa','h','Or0','sigma8']

sample = MCSamples(samples=samps,names = names, labels = names)
#g = gplot.getSinglePlotter(chain_dir=r'%s'%dire)
#sample = g.sampleAnalyser.samplesForRoot('LCDM')
#sample = g.sampleAnalyser.samplesForRoot('7CPL')
param = sample.getParams()


mean=[]
lower=[]
upper=[]

lower1=[]
upper1=[]

lower2=[]
upper2=[]


def hubble_n_s(Ophi,  rd, li, mi,  Orad_i, h, sigma8,z):
 fun = scalarpow(Ophi,  rd, li, mi,  Orad_i, h, sigma8).hubble_normalized_z(z)
# H1 = 1 + q0
 return fun**2.

 
def hubble_norm_z(Ophi,  rd, li, mi,  Orad_i, h, sigma8,z):
 fun = scalarpow(Ophi,     rd, li, mi,  Orad_i*1e-5, h, 0.045, 0.96, sigma8).hubble_normalized_z(z)
 return fun 


def hubble_z(Ophi,  rd, li, mi,  Orad_i, h, sigma8,z):
 fun = scalarpow(Ophi,     rd, li, mi,  Orad_i*1e-5, h, 0.045, 0.96, sigma8).hubble_normalized_z(z)
# return fun*100.*h0
 return fun*100.*h
print(hubble_z(1.99,147.49,0.50,0.0032,0.11,0.7,0.8,0.0))


def equation_of_state_z(Ophi,  rd, li, mi,  Orad_i, h, sigma8,z):
 fun = scalarpow(Ophi,     rd, li, mi,  Orad_i*1e-5, h, 0.045, 0.96, sigma8).equation_of_state_z(z)
 return fun 
print(equation_of_state_z(1.99,147.49,0.50,0.0032,0.11,0.7,0.8,0.0))
 
 
z=np.linspace(0,1.5,10)
for i in z:


#z=np.linspace(0,5,10)
#for i in z:

  
  
  
  EoS = np.vectorize(equation_of_state_z) 
  derived = EoS(param.Ophi, param.rd, param.li, param.mi, param.Orad_i, param.h, param.sigma8,i)
   
# cpl OM(z) 
#  hubble_d = np.vectorize(dummy) 
#  hubble = np.vectorize(hubble_n_s)
#  derived = ((2.*(1.+i)*hubble_d(param.Ophi, param.rd, param.li, param.mi, param.Orad_i, param.h, param.sigma8,i))/3. -1.)/(1.- ((1.-param.Ophi-param.Orad_i)*(1.+i)**3./(hubble(param.Ophi, param.rd, param.li, param.mi, param.Orad_i, param.h, param.sigma8,i))))
  
  #m=sample.mean(derived)
  
  m=sample[~np.isnan(derived)].mean()
  #print(m)  


  print(np.nanmean(m))
    
  mean.append(m)
  
  #mean=mean+m  
  
  print(mean)

  #lcdm = np.sqrt(hubble_n_s(.27,4.68*1e-5,-1,0,z))
  s=sample.twoTailLimits(derived,0.683)
  s1=sample.twoTailLimits(derived,0.954)
  s2=sample.twoTailLimits(derived,0.997)
  lower.append(s[0])
  upper.append(s[1])
  lower1.append(s1[0])
  upper1.append(s1[1])
  lower2.append(s2[0])
  upper2.append(s2[1])
  print('z:%f mean:%f  lower:%f  upper:%f'%(i,m,s[0],s[1]))


  #s=sample.twoTailLimits(derived,0.683)
  #s1=sample.twoTailLimits(derived,0.954)
  #s2=sample.twoTailLimits(derived,0.997)
  #lower=lower+s[0]
  #upper=upper+s[1]
  #lower1=lower1+s1[0]
  #upper1=upper1+s1[1]
  #lower2=lower2+s2[0]
  #upper2=upper2+s2[1]
  #print('z:%f mean:%f  lower:%f  upper:%f'%(i,m,s[0],s[1]))

#rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
#rc('text', usetex=True)

#plt.plot((0, 2), (-1, -1) , 'k--',linewidth=0.4)

#plt.plot(z, mean, 'red', linewidth=.6)
plt.plot(z, (upper-lower)/2.0, 'blue', linewidth=.6)

#plt.plot(z,lcdm, 'k-',linewidth=0.3 )



plt.plot(z,lower,  'blueviolet',linewidth=.3)
plt.plot(z,upper,  'blueviolet',linewidth=.3)
plt.plot(z,lower1, 'darkviolet',linewidth=.3)
plt.plot(z,upper1, 'darkviolet',linewidth=.3)
plt.fill_between(z,lower,upper, color='mediumorchid', alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(z,lower1,upper1, color='violet', alpha=0.5)
#plt.plot(z,lower2, 'r-.',linewidth=1.5)
#plt.plot(z,upper2, 'r-.',linewidth=1.5)
#plt.xlim(0.001,1.3)
#plt.plot(z,(upper-lower)/2.0, 'blueviolet',linewidth=.3)


plt.xlim(0,1.5)
plt.ylim(-1.5,-0.7)

plt.xlabel(r'$z$')
plt.ylabel(r'$w_{DE}(z)$')
plt.savefig('w_mean.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')
```

when I use "m=sample.mean(derived)", mean value prints "NaN". But, with with "m=sample[~np.isnan(derived)].mean()" mean is not "NaN" but the results are incorrect and so is the appearance of mean value in the plot. Hence, I tried to find the mean using "mean =(upper-lower)/2". But then the error it shows is this

> 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "omn_der31_wrong_meanvalue.py", line 133, in <module>
    plt.plot(z, (upper-lower)/2.0, 'blue', linewidth=.6)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

I am not proficient in python so unable figure out the solution. Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Without mean the graph appears smooth. But the mean value is necessary to compare with the standard results.

Comment: I can't find any variable here called upper and lower. Could you add some details, how you get them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since the mean value is NaN, it does not appear in the plot as well. So, I thought to calculate it using "mean = (upper-lower)/2". But an error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'" occurred. All I want is a mean value plotted on the graph. Currently, I can only plot upper and lower 1 sigma and 2 sigma values.  Modifying to "print('z:%f mean:%f  lower:%f  upper:%f'%(i,(s[1]-s[0])/2.,s[0],s[1]))" prints mean for different redshifts 'z' but again at the end the code is getting killed. Please help.

Comment: @ArpadHorvath--СлаваУкраїні  upper and lower are list of variables that can take different values for different redshifts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want average, you should use addition with arrays instead of lists.

```py
import numpy as np

upper = [1, 4, 2, 42]
lower = [-1, 2, 1, 0]

average = (np.array(upper) + np.array(lower)) / 2
# gives you array([ 0. ,  3. ,  1.5, 21. ])
```

Comment: @ArpadHorvath--СлаваУкраїнi  Thank you for your answer. I though have found another solution to the problem similar to this.